# Using PHP to Convert ASCII Character to Decimal Equivalent

Tags: php, ascii, decimal

Can someone suggest a (preferably) graceful way to convert an ASCII character to its decimal equivalent using PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function ascii_to_dec($str)
{
  for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i++) {
    $dec_array[] = ord($str{$i});
  }
  return $dec_array;
}
```

**example usage :**

```
$ascii ="\t";
print_r( ascii_to_dec($ascii));
```

**returns  an array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
)
```

Comment: Inverse function: foreach ($dec_array as $dec_code) { $str .= chr($dec_code); }

Answer (score 5):

[`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) is what you need

Answer (score 3):

[ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) returns the integer ascii value of a character

[chr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) returns a character from an ascii value

Answer (score 1):

Try [ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto streetparade's answer

```
foreach ($array as $decval)
{
  echo $decval;
}
```

returns raw dec for the characters.