# Convert random text to a number with PHP

Tags: php, string, random, converters

I need to convert a random text to a number. But the ramdom text has always to be converted to the same number. For example:

```
xxxx -> 10
testing -> 396
stackoverflow -> 72
```

I cant use the number of characters to convert the `string` cause if I have 2 strings with the same number `characters` they need to have a different number (at most times at least).

I do not need to have this number in a range. No! It can be any number, since it will always be the same given a certain string.

Comment: Would this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836152/using-php-to-convert-ascii-character-to-decimal-equivalent

Comment: What are the constraints of the text, alphanumeric, alpha only, lowercase only ???

Comment: It's a slow way provided in that post. Ord is great but it only work for the first char! Thank you

Comment: The constraints  of the text is alphanumeric Mr. @Orangepill

Comment: upper and lower? no spaces? and other special chars

Comment: upper and lower does not matter Mr. @Orangepill ! Thank you!

Comment: You can enumerate each character and then combine the individual ordinals. However, how you do this is dependent on your requirements on the generated numbers. You require that two equal-length strings produce different ordinals. So a sum of ordinals will not work, since a word and its reverse then will have the same value. `crc32` might be something for you to look into.

Comment: An explanation of your application may help us help you find the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using hashes (`md5`, `sha1`, etc):

```
$number = hexdec( md5("hello world") );
$number = hexdec( sha1("hello world") );
```

Hashes of the same string will transform to the same number.

Comment: A `crc32` would be faster, if that matters in this case. Finally, and most importantly, it will convert to float in case the result cannot fit in an integer.

Comment: Maybe you can add salt to prevent collisions?

Comment: No need to use md5 or sha1. hexdec will already skip non-hexadecimal characters!

Answer (score 2):

What about;

```
$number = crc32($string);
```

Should be cheap, gives integer output, and produce reasonable randomness for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods that have been shown have the potential of having collisions. The following should not.

```
$num = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    $num .= str_pad(ord($str[$i]), 3 "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
return $num;
```

Comment: You would quickly outrun 32 bit, and waste quite a bit of the range.

Comment: I agree with that. I'm promoting my answer for `crc32`.

Comment: I would agree if you drop the 'unique' constraint on the problem... god knows it's faster then the other solutions as well.

Comment: I'm starting to think the only way to guarantee uniqueness as well as eliminate key collisions is going to be to push the string into a database table with a unique key constraint on the string and a auto incrementing primary key and return the key value.

Comment: My interpretion of the author by the comments is that eliminating the possibility of key collision is not prioritized. Clearly, uniqueness is important if this is to go into a database. So i guess he would just have to check if the produced number already exists.

Comment: at least you could get 4 chars per int by combining `ord()` with bitwise `shift` and `or`.

Comment: The uniquiness would be a "must" but it is not necessary. I made about 2 hours of research and I did not come with any idea to make a unique number from a string. The one alternative that I found is  multiply the ord of the character by it's position (1, 2, 3, 4...) so it looks like would be unique. But I am not totatly sure of that!

Comment: mathematically it would still be possible to get a collision.