# Using PHP to Convert Decimal to ASCII using SPACE delimiters

Tags: php, decimal, ascii, chr

**Using PHP, how do you convert a string of decimal numbers with spaces in between into a string without spaces?** (unless of course it is a DEC space (32) converted)

Example: 84 104 97 110 107 32 121 111 117

I have checked out the related questions and most of them are just asking what the built in function is for converting decimal to ascii. I know chr() and ord() and I think the solution really should use explode() and implode() along with a string replace. I am just horrible at for and foreach loops so the logic breaks my mind. :)

The closest SO topic I found is this one which is basically the opposite of what I am asking for - 
[Using PHP to Convert ASCII Character to Decimal Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836152/using-php-to-convert-ascii-character-to-decimal-equivalent)

Comment: you want to remove spaces, why then title says convert decimal to ascii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a situation where the `strtok` function actually could be used for something.

The `strtok` function tokenizes a string based on a character. In this case the token delimiter is a space. Each time you call `strtok` it returns the next token in the string.

The `chr` function is used to convert the ordinal (decimal) number to its ASCII character equivalent.

```
function myParseString($str) {
    $output = ''; // What we will return
    $token = strtok($str, ' '); // Initialize the tokenizer

    // Loop until there are no more tokens left
    while ($token !== false) {
        $output .= chr($token); // Add the token to the output
        $token = strtok(' '); // Advance the tokenizer, getting the next token
    }
    // All the tokens have been consumed, return the result!
    return $output;
}
$str = '84 104 97 110 107 32 121 111 117';
echo myParseString($str);
```

(And you are welcome.)

Comment: wow... that went way beyond what I thought it would be. It works perfectly! Thanks again.